# Можно ли употребить словосочетания «предложить уговор» и «предложить ряду»?

Tags: лексика, синонимы, словосочетания, устаревшие-слова

Интересует правильность подобных словосочетаний. Хочу заменить слово "сделка", и нужен более архаичный вариант.

1. *Хочу предложить тебе ряду* ("ряда" от "рядить")*, от которой ты не сможешь отказаться.*
2. *Хочу предложить тебе уговор, от которого ты не сможешь отказаться.*

Если есть ещё какие-то синонимы?
С радостью восполню лакуну в своих познаниях. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1.** Синонимы к слову "сделка" есть [здесь](https://classes.ru/all-russian/russian-dictionary-synonyms-term-77732.htm).
**2.** *Предложить уговор* — да, так говорят.

> — Думаешь, поздно нам с тобой договариваться? — спросил Пафнутьев, обеспокоенный последними словами Самохина. Было в них что-то истинное, Самохин не пытался выкрутиться, он просто **предложил уговор**, и что-то важное стояло за этим предложением.
> Виктор Пронин. Купите девочку

**3.** В словаре Даля:
[ряд](http://www.endic.ru/dal/Rjad-36377.html) — условие, договор, торг и соглашенье, обязательство по воле, взаимная сделка в торговле, ремеслах и пр. *Не было б ряду, не было б и спору, т. е. требую исполненья по ряду и по условию.*

В словаре Ефремовой:
**ряд** — 3. ***м.** устар.* Условие, соглашение, договор (на Руси IX-XIII вв.).

Считаю, что можно так сказать:
*Хочу предложить тебе **ряд, от которого** ты не сможешь отказаться.*
Обратите внимание, что глагол [предложить](http://gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C) управляет винительным падежом (*предложить — **что?***).

**Дополнение 1** (после комментария)

Даль: **Ряда** **ж.** ряд, условие, договор или соглашенье, подряд, сделка при покупке, заказах, поставках, стройках, найме и пр. *Я **без ряды** отдал работу, не рядился, после сочтемся.*

МАС: [ря́да](https://gufo.me/dict/mas/%D1%80%D1%8F%D0%B4%D0%B0), -ы, ***ж.** устар.* Действие по глаг. рядиться 2 (в 1 знач.); соглашение, договор.
[Марфа:] *Да ведь это как вам угодно, Евлалия Андреевна; хотите мою службу ни во что поставить, так поставьте. Разве я смею требовать; у нас **ряды не было*** (А. Островский. Невольницы).

Ну вот! Разобрались: можно использовать и слово женского рода (*предложить ряду*).

**Дополнение 2**
Спасибо за вопрос. Если интересуют устаревшие слова, то можно обратиться к словарю русских народных говоров. Слово [**ряда**](https://iling.spb.ru/vocabula/srng/srng_35.pdf) в нем тоже имеется (в разных значениях; стр. 340).

Comment: ~глагол предложить управляет винительным падежом~
Да, у меня были сомнения и по этому поводу. Спасибо большое, что разрешили их; за все остальные пояснения тоже благодарю.

Comment: Есть ещё и такой вариант слова: 
https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/ряда
Его тоже, получается, можно использовать с "предложить"?

Comment: Получается, что да. Я внесла дополнения в свой ответ.

Comment: @JohnnyFox На сайте принято благодарить участников за все полезные вопросы и ответы стрелочкой (треугольником) вверх, а также принимать один из ответов на свой вопрос галочкой.